# Eliminate $\theta$ from $4x=5\cos\theta -\cos 5\theta$ and $4y=5\sin\theta -\sin 5\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Eliminate $\theta$ from the equations.
$$4x=5\cos\theta -\cos 5\theta$$
$$4y=5\sin\theta -\sin 5\theta$$

Alternative forms are

$$x=5\cos^3\theta-4\cos^5\theta$$
$$y=5\sin^3\theta-4\sin^5\theta$$

and $$x=\cos^3\theta(3-2\cos2\theta)$$
$$y=\sin^3\theta(3+2\cos2\theta)$$

Comment: One of the moves you can do in this situation is to go to the exponential forms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ - which sometimes clarifies issues.

Comment: Another approach — which amounts to something close to the exponential form, just in a slightly different shape — is to use the half-tangent substitution to get $x$ and $y$ as rational functions of $t=\tan(\theta/2)$ and then use the usual elimination techniques to get an implicit equation relating $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $c=\cos2\theta$.

$$4x=5\cos\theta -\cos 5\theta\tag1$$
$$4y=5\sin\theta -\sin 5\theta\tag2$$

Squaring and adding ,$$16(x^2+y^2)=25+1-10\cos4\theta$$ $$8(x^2+y^2)=13-5(2c^2-1)$$ $$5c^2=9-4(x^2+y^2)=k$$

Squaring and subtracting, $$16(x^2-y^2)=25\cos2\theta+\cos10\theta-10\cos6\theta$$ $$16(x^2-y^2)=25c+(16c^5-20c^3+5c)-10(4c^3-3c)$$ $$4(x^2-y^2)=c(4c^4-15c^2+15)$$

Substituting $k$,
$$100(x^2-y^2)=c(4k^2-75k+375)$$

Further simplifying leads to, $$25(x^2-y^2)=c(16\lambda^2+3\lambda+6)$$ where $\lambda=(x^2+y^2)$.

Squaring again and replacing all values finally we get, $$3125(x^2-y^2)^2=[9-4(x^2+y^2)][16(x^2+y^2)^2+3(x^2+y^2)+6]^2$$

And this is that [epicycloid](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B+3125%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29%5E2%3D%3D%289-4%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29%28+16+%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E2+%2B3+%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29+%2B6%29%5E2%5D), as being described in @orangeskid's answer!

Comment: Very nice!  Somehow there is a sign off, it should be $+ 3(x^2+y^2)$, can you check your calculations?  The plot with $+$ seems the correct one.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B+3125%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29%5E2%3D%3D%289-4%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29%28+16+%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E2+%2B3+%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29+%2B6%29%5E2%5D

Comment: @orangeskid , that was a silly mistake, now corrected. Thanks : )

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Eliminating $\cos 2\theta$ is the key idea. I think this is the canonical answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

These are the parametric equations of an [epicycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid#Equations), where the large circle has radius $R=1$, and the smaller exterior rolling circle has radius $r=\frac{1}{4}$.

A possible simplification is writing
$$4a=4(x+i y) = 5 z - z^ 5\\
4b=4(x-i y) = \frac{5}{z} - \frac{1}{z^5}$$
where $z = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$
and get a relation between $a$, $b$, that implies a relation between $x$ and $y$, see [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%20%7B4%20a%20-%285%20z-%20z%5E5%29%2C%204%20b%20-%285%2Fz%20-1%2Fz%5E5%29%7D%2C%20%7Ba%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bz%7D%5D). Or, we can just give the result provided by [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%20%7B4%28x%2Bi%20y%29%20-%20%285z%20-%20z%5E5%29%2C%204%28x-i%20y%29%20-%20%285%2Fz%20-%201%2Fz%5E5%29%7D%2C%20%7Bx%2Cy%7D%2C%20%7Bz%7D%5D) :

$$-81 - 45 x^2 + 365 x^4 - 15 x^6 - 480 x^8 + 256 x^{10} - 45 y^2 - 2395 x^2 y^2 - 45 x^4 y^2 - 1920 x^6 y^2 + 1280 x^8 y^2 + 365 y^4 - 45 x^2 y^4 - 2880 x^4 y^4 + 2560 x^6 y^4 - 15 y^6 - 1920 x^2 y^6 + 2560 x^4 y^6 - 480 y^8 + 1280 x^2 y^8 + 256 y^{10}=0$$

a curve of degree $10$
[[image: epicycloid, <span class=]$4$ leaves" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hf3W1.jpg)

We can simplify the defining polynomial by writing it as a polynomial in $x^2 + y^2$ and $x^2 y^2$.

$\bf{Added:}$ Following the solution of @ACB: we have the polar representation ($x = r \cos \phi$, $y=r \sin \phi$)

$$\cos^2 2 \phi = \frac{(9 - 4 r^2)(16 r^4+ 3 r^2 + 6)^2}{3125 r^4}= f(r)$$

The function in $r>0$ on RHS is strictly decreasing on $(0, \infty)$. Indeed, we [have](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5B%289-4%20r%5E2%29%28%2016%20r%5E4%20%2B3%20r%5E2%20%2B6%29%5E2%2F%20%28%20r%5E4%29%2Cr%5D)
$$f'(r) = -24\, \frac{(-1 + r^2)^2 (9 + 16 r^2) (6 + 3 r^2 + 16 r^4)}{3125\, r^5}$$
Now, $f(1) = 1$, and $f(\frac{3}{2})=0$. We see that our curve is situated between the circles of radius $1$, and $\frac{3}{2} = 1 + 2\cdot \frac{1}{4}$, as it should.

So now we can write the curve in polar coordinates
$$r = f^{-1}(\cos^2 2\phi)$$
where $f^{-1}\colon [0,1]\to [1, \frac{3}{2}]$ is the inverse function of $f$.

Comment: There is most likely a form involving fractional exponents such as $(x+y)^{\frac{2}{3}}+(x-y)^{\frac{2}{3}}=1$.

Comment: @Rene Schipperus: That must be the astroid,  the small circle rolls inside. But there may be some simpler algebraic form for the curve. Very interesting...

Comment: By various manipulations similar to a previous question I asked with $3$ instead of $5$, I get $x^2+y^2=16w^2+11w+1$ and $x^2y^2=w^3(5+16w)^2$ where $w=\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta$. One can now divide the quadratic into the quartic getting a linear remainder, and using the quadratic formula, isolate  the square root, and squaring, get an algebraic relation.

Comment: @Rene Schipperus: It seems that finding polynomial relations is in some sense a mechanical thing.  The astroid has a big polynomial equation, while the algebraic one is quite neat. One can show that the polynomial one implies the algebraic, by making a substitution $x^2=a^3, y^2 = b^3$, in the polynomial, and then factoring (magically, a factor $a+b-1$ appears). It does not seem to work for this curve at hand.  Or maybe it works with other substitutions. An interesting curve...

Comment: Simplifying by hand I got, $3125(x^2-y^2)^2=[9-4(x^2+y^2)][16(x^2+y^2)^2-3(x^2+y^2)+6]^2.$ According to wolfram alpha, the graph looks like [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+3125%28x%5E2-y%5E2%29%5E2%3D%5B9-4%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5D%5B16%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%5E2-3%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%2B6%5D%5E2). Any idea?

Comment: If you are interested, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/5101/232)'s how I reached my solution. (Because I noted my previous comment has been upvoted)

Comment: @ACB: That is very interesting!  And I think it is the right approach, if we don't use a CAS.

Comment: @ACB Will you publish your calculation as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ACB : I revised the calculations, your formula is right! ! ( just a - sign off) : $3125 q^2 = (9-4p)(16 p^2 + 3 p +6)^2$, with $q=x^2-y^2$, $p=x^2+y^2$. Wonderful! Please publish your solution!