# Alternative cartesian equation for epicycloid (quatrefoil)

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions, cycloid

In the [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4342525/1008807):

> Eliminate $\theta$ from the system of equations.
> $$x\sin\theta-y\cos\theta=-\sin4\theta$$
> $$x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta=\frac52-\frac32\cos4\theta$$

it is stated in a [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3214492/1008807) that the resultant is

$$x^{10}+5 x^8 y^2+10 x^6 x^4 + 10 x^4 y^6+5 x^2 y^8+y^{10}-705 x^8+12180 x^6 y^2 -24230 x^4 y^4+12180 x^2 y^6-705 y^8+122560 x^6-112320 x^4 y^2 -112320 x^2 y^4 +122560 y^6+599040 x^4-1361920 x^2 y^2 +599040 y^4+327680 x^2+327680 y^2-1048576=0$$

(generated via *Mathematica*)

which ultimately turned out to be

$$\boldsymbol{(x+y)^{2/5}+(x-y)^{2/5}=2}$$

that was accomplished by the parametrization,
$$x=\cos(\theta)\,(5-4\cos^4(\theta)),$$
$$y=\sin(\theta)\,(5-4\sin^4(\theta)).$$

That represents the cartesian equation of the evolute of an [astroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid).(?)

With the victory over that problem (thanks to @Claude Leibovici), I was attracted by another similar problem: [Eliminate $\theta$ from $4x=5\cos\theta -\cos 5\theta$ and $4y=5\sin\theta -\sin 5\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4290398/1008807), where the answer is the equation of an [epicycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid).

In that question, one can find that
$$x=\cos^3(\theta)\,(5-4\cos^2(\theta))$$
$$y=\sin^3(\theta)\,(5-4\sin^2(\theta))$$

which seems almost similar to the aforementioned approach.

Also as mentioned in one answer, the eliminant is
$$-81 - 45 x^2 + 365 x^4 - 15 x^6 - 480 x^8 + 256 x^{10} - 45 y^2 - 2395 x^2 y^2 - 45 x^4 y^2 - 1920 x^6 y^2 + 1280 x^8 y^2 + 365 y^4 - 45 x^2 y^4 - 2880 x^4 y^4 + 2560 x^6 y^4 - 15 y^6 - 1920 x^2 y^6 + 2560 x^4 y^6 - 480 y^8 + 1280 x^2 y^8 + 256 y^{10}=0$$

(generated via *Wolfram|Alpha*)

So because of the similarity, there may be a neat solution as before.

I tried plugging some possible equations in *Wolfram|Alpha* and *Desmos* graphing calculator, seeking for a hint. Yet, I haven't found the exit.

> **Question**. Can there be a nice equation for this curve?

---

If it helps, here's a table showing the coefficients of each term of each polynomial (for the ease of comparison).

|  | $(x+y)^{2/5}+(x-y)^{2/5}=2$ | unknown |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $x^{10},y^{10}$ | 1 | 256 |
| $x^8,y^8$ | -705 | -480 |
| $x^6,y^6$ | 122560 | -15 |
| $x^4,y^4$ | 599040 | 365 |
| $x^2,y^2$ | 327680 | -45 |
| $x^8y^2,x^2y^8$ | 5 | 1280 |
| $x^6y^4,x^4y^6$ | 10 | 2560 |
| $x^6y^2,x^2y^6$ | 12108 | -1920 |
| $x^4y^2,x^2y^4$ | -112320 | -45 |
| $x^2y^2$ | -1361920 | -2395 |
| $x^4y^4$ | -24230 | -2880 |
| constant | -1048576 | -81 |

Curves:

[image: epicycloid&hypocycloid]

The red curve is the hypocycloid and the other is the epicycloid.

The symmetry of these curves is probably implying that they have well formed equations too.

Answer (score 4):

If we have $$x=\cos^3(\theta)\,(5-4\cos^2(\theta))$$
$$y=\sin^3(\theta)\,(5-4\sin^2(\theta))$$ then, using $S=(x^2+y^2)$
$$S=\frac{1}{8} (13-5 \cos (4 \theta))\implies \theta_\pm=\pm\frac 14 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{13-8S}{5} \right)$$

What can you do with this ?

Comment: I still don't see what to do with the last result.

Comment: @ACB. Me neither !